# Pattern Matching Scala, access the values

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I have a list with Strings. For example: `10001_20180101010101_SOURCE_Text`

I want to make an if statement for all of the strings such as if the ID from the first String is greater than the ID from the second String then `print("anything")` and so on.

I tried with pattern matching like this:

```
val pattern = raw"([0-9]+)_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(SOURCE|DEL)_(.*)".r
"some string" match {
  case pattern(id, year, month, day, hour, min, sec, typee, name: String) => 
    println(s"$id $year $month $day $hour $min $sec $typee $name")
  case _ => println("No match")
}
```

Can I somehow access id, year, month...?

Comment: Do you have an example input to test?  
What do you mean "access"? When you do `s"$id"` you are accessing the id variable

Comment: Perhaps, `val pattern(id, year, month, day, hour, min, sec, typee, name: String) = myString`?

Comment: I have a list with Strings.
For example: "10001_20180101010101_SOURCE_Text"
I want to make a if statement for all of the strings... 
if the ID from the first String is greater than the ID from the second String then print("anything") and so on.

Comment: You would have to store the variable you want to access elsewhere, like in @Rich's answer

Answer (score 3):

> I have a list with Strings. For example: "10001_20180101010101_SOURCE_Text" I want to make a if statement for all of the strings... if the ID from the first String is greater than the ID from the second String then print("anything") and so on.

Something like this?

```
case class Record(id: Int, year: Int, month: Int)

val pattern = raw"([0-9]+)_(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})_(TEXT|text|Text)_(.*)".r

def parse(record): Option[Record] =
  "some string" match {
    case pattern(id, year, month, day, hour, min, sec, typee, name: String) => 
      Some(Record(id, year, month))
      // println(s"$id $year $month $day $hour $min $sec $typee $name")
    case _ => None
      // println("No match")

val inputRecords: List[String] = ... // from input

val records: List[Record] = inputRecords.flatMap(parse)

if (records.get(0).id > records.get(1).id)
   print("anything")
```

Comment: I am sorry to hear that. You'll need to update your question with more info if you want further help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask